# Excel Return Value based on 2 Criteria: 1.between dates and ID Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 Excel sheets (sheet A and B) that have different data that I need combined based on the following criteria:

1. a.id = b.id
2. a.date between b.start_date and b.end_date

The data looks something like this:

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52B15.jpg)

So I want to return Attribute 1 and combine/join it to sheet A, but only if a.date is between b.start_date and b.end_date.

Thank you so much!